# Docker installation fails on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, server

I'm trying to install Docker on Windows Server 2019 (*not* Docker Desktop--it doesn't work on Windows Server; we've already tried). I am following this guide: https://blog.sixeyed.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-windows-server-2019/. I run the following in an escalated PowerShell window (and logged in with local Administrator account)

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

That part succeeds, so I go to the next step:

```
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -verbose
```

I get the following error:

```
> VERBOSE: Using the provider 'DockerMsftProvider' for searching
> packages. WARNING: Cannot find path
> 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\4\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json'
> because it does not exist. WARNING: Cannot bind argument to parameter
> 'downloadURL' because it is an empty string. WARNING: The property
> 'AbsoluteUri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
> exists. WARNING: The property 'RequestMessage' cannot be found on this
> object. Verify that the property exists. Install-Package : No match
> was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'docker'.
> Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -verbos ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
> Ex    ception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I've read several forums about this error and so I've also tried:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

... but I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Cannot find path
'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\4\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json' because it does not
exist.
WARNING: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'downloadURL' because it is an empty string.
WARNING: The property 'AbsoluteUri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: The property 'RequestMessage' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Docker'. Try Get-PackageSource
to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Most of the forums I've read on this issue are related to a Proxy issue, however the VM is not behind a proxy--just a Cisco firewall--and Windows Defender Firewall is completely disabled.

I verified that the Container feature has been installed, as well as Hyper-V. And since the machine is a VM and so I also enabled "Expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest OS" and "Enable virtualized CPU performance counters" in VMware.

Comment: Are you running on the PS console or ISE? Are you running as admin?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was apparently with the ciphers in Windows Registry. After running Get-PackageSource, IsTrusted for DockerDefault was False. So we ran IIS Crypto CLI (in CMD: .\iiscryptocli.exe /template default /reboot) to reset the Windows encryption registry keys to default and after rebooting, the Docker install succeeded. So I guess that the PowerShell Install-package cmdlet was unable to get the JSON file needed to help install Docker from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825636&clcid=0x409 because of an encryption negotiation problem.

Answer (score -2):

I know this thread is quite old now, but I have been faced to the same problem on a Windows Server 2019. Since the server was new, there was no cipher problem as described in the first answer (I have tried it anyway).

So, I have downloaded the DockerMsftIndex.json into the missing file :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dockermsft.azureedge.net/dockercontainer/DockerMsftIndex.json" `
                  -OutFile $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json
```

Unfortunally, the DockerMsftProvider deletes the file when trying to install Docker again.

You simply need to mark the file as read-only :

```
(Get-Item $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json).Attributes = [IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
```

and tada :) the install package cmdlet finally accept to work (despite a 404 error, Docker is correctly installed - don't forget to reboot the server).

However, this installation method seems no longer supported since Docker EE has now a paid support from Mirantis (last version you can install this way is 20.10.9), [See here for Docker CE or containerd installs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce)

Hope this will help :)