# Docker Installation fails on secure agent

Tags: windows, azure, docker, agent

I ran the following powershell script:

```
write-output "Installing nuger package provider";
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
Install-PackageProvider -name nuget -force;
if (-not $?) {
   Write-Error 'Install package provider failed'
   exit 1
}
write-output "Installing Docker module";
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force;
if (-not $?) {
  Write-Error 'Install docker module failed'
  exit 1
}

write-output "Installing Docker package";
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force;
if (-not $?) {
    Write-Error 'Install docker package failed'
    exit 1
}
```

But getting the following error at the last step:

[image]

I have tried everything i could find on the internet, even this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954153/docker-installation-fails-on-windows-server-2019#:~:text=The%20issue%20was%20apparently%20with%20the%20ciphers%20in,default%20and%20after%20rebooting%2C%20the%20Docker%20install%20succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954153/docker-installation-fails-on-windows-server-2019#:%7E:text=The%20issue%20was%20apparently%20with%20the%20ciphers%20in,default%20and%20after%20rebooting%2C%20the%20Docker%20install%20succeeded).

But nothing has helped.

What am i missing?

Comment: ``Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe -OutFile DockerInstaller.exe``

Comment: ``Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\DockerInstaller.exe``

Comment: > docker version

Answer (score 0):

While using your [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) got the same Error and I tried another approach.

- I tried below are steps:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri [https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe](https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe "https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/docker%20desktop%20installer.exe") -OutFile DockerInstaller.exe
```

[image]

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\DockerInstaller.exe
```

[image]

[image]

```
docker version
```

[image]

Comment: But i don't want a user prompt, as it would be run on an agent using ps script.

Comment: I have used only PowerShell scripts ``Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\DockerInstaller.exe``` will activate the installed docker. ``Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing. I have checked this as well ```https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1" -o install-docker-ce.ps1
.\install-docker-ce.ps1```. It good helped.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps as mentioned in this link helped:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  Please consider adding the relevant detail of the link in your answer, as links can and DO go dead!